# Assigning Integers to Variables in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm sorry that this is a beginner question. I just trying to let x = 5, y = 2, and set all other variables to zero in a function s. All this work is to verify p computes 5! in the code below, where p representing

y:=1 ; while ¬(x=1) do (y:=y*x; x:=x-1);

```
type Num = Integer
type Var = String
type Z = Integer
type T = Bool
type State = Var -> Z

data Aexp = N Num | V Var | Add Aexp Aexp | Mult Aexp Aexp | Sub Aexp Aexp deriving (Show, Eq, Read)
data Bexp = TRUE | FALSE | Eq Aexp Aexp | Le Aexp Aexp | Neg Bexp | And Bexp Bexp deriving (Show, Eq, Read)
data Stm  = Ass Var Aexp | Skip | Comp Stm Stm | If Bexp Stm Stm | While Bexp Stm deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

p::Stm

p = (Comp(Ass "y" (N 1))(While(Neg(Eq (V "x") (N 1)))(Comp (Ass "y" (Mult (V "y") (V "x")))(Ass "x" (Sub (V "x") (N 1))))))

s :: State {- It has to be Var -> Int-}
s x = 5
s y = 2
```

And when I try to compile this, ghci gives that the pattern matches are overlapped. I know this is a quite simple question, but there is not much information online for me to solve this. Could you give me any hints? Thanks!

Comment: What's the definition of the `Var` type?

Comment: Var is string. Sorry I didn't make this clear.@Lee

Comment: Pattern matching issues aside, you are implementing the wrong function. You need a map to *store* variable/expression associations that can change as your evaluator encounters `Ass` statements. Your evaluator will use that to evaluate `V` values by replacing them with the value stored in your map.

Comment: Your grammar is also ambiguous; if you have three statements, is that `Comp (Comp a b) c` or `Comp a (Comp b c)`? Depending on your evaluator, you may get different results for each.

Answer (score 2):

You are pattern matching. This is typically done using different values of the argument type.

```
didSayHello :: String -> Bool
didSayHello "hello" = True
didSayHello x       = False
```

This matches top-down, reading "if the string argument is 'hello', then True" and "if it is any random String argument (excluding 'hello'), then False"

Your matches are overlapping because in both patterns you're referring to any random String place holder. The one just happened to be called "x" and the other "y".

See [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching) link for more details

Comment: Thank you! I know what is the problem right now, but I don't know how to fix it under this situation(Var -> Int). I've updated the question to make it clear.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but would this fix it (notice the quotes, also there should be newlines between each snippet)?

`s :: Var -> Int`
`s "x" = 5`
`s "y" = 2`

Comment: From what I can gather you want to have a lookup function, mapping variable names to Integer values. This could be done using the actual variable names. `s "x" = 5` and `s "y" = 2`. What is your intention? Do you wish to set the value of "y" to 2, giving you `(Comp(Ass "y" (N 2))(...`?

Comment: I just want p computing the factorial of 5 when applied to s. And s is a constant which maps x to 5 and y to 2, and all other variables to zero.

Comment: Nearly all the data types in Haskell are immutable, so it won't be possible to alter `p`. Everything in Haskell is an expression, so if you want the structure of `p`, but with different value, you'll have to recreate it, containing the new values. You could have a function that creates the object for you and places arguments in strategic places, for a simplified example, `assign v n = Ass v (N n)`.

Answer (score 1):

The two alternatives are doing exactly the same thing: matching on *any* value passed in, and calling it `x`. Since the first case matches *anything* it always succeeds and returns `5`.

To do what you seem to be trying to do, you cannot use pattern matching, you need to use equality (via the Eq class):

```
s :: Var -> Int
s v | v == x = 5
    | v == y = 3
```

You cannot pattern match against other values, only patterns. `x` and `y` are values when you defined them using let, but `x` and `y` are patterns (matching absolutely any input value)

You mentioned that Var is a `String`, so this won't work if `x` and `y` are set like `let x = 5, y = 2` because there is no instance for `Num String`, so `x` and `y` won't be `String`s, and can't be tested for equality with a `Var`

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear what you are trying to do, but know that assignment does not really exist in Haskell. Perhaps you want to look at

```
s string = 
  let 
    x = 5
    y = 2
  in
  -- something using x and y, e.g.
  x + y
```

In this case s will return 7 no matter what string you pass it, i.e. :

```
s "alpha" => 7
s "beta"  => 7
```

Comment: I'm sorry about this. I just updated my question to make it clear. Hope you could understand this better. I know where the problem is, but I just don't know how to fix it by not changing the condition Var -> Int.